# How to create a delay between two textBox displaying in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, delay, displayobject

I want to display two textboxes with delay of 2 seconds. (initially textBoxes are hidden)
In simply ,one after another.

I used System.threading.thread.sleep()
but no use.

Help me Pro's 
Im a beginner

Comment: *Never* use Thread.Sleep() in a GUI app.  You must use a Timer.  In its Tick event, set the Visible property to true and stop the timer.

Comment: can you kindly tell me how to use Timers in my GUI ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAML, put a story board in your XAML to show your textbox with a delay. You can fire it on a event (like page loaded) or click or DataTrigger etc.